# Adjusted Rand Index with different size inputs

Tags: clustering, python, partitioning

Forgive me if my terminology is off, this concept is somewhat new to me.

I'm trying to run an ARI calculation between two partitions which contain a different number of clusters, where each cluster can also vary in size. I'm not really sure what is the correct approach to take when running the calculation.

A bit of background...

I am running this in python and I have two lists:

```
List1 = [[41, 42], [145, 146, 206], [155, 216], [208, 209]...] etc

List2 = [[637, 698, 759], [696, 757, 818], [811, 872], [881, 942, 941, 1003, 943, 944, 1005, 1004, 1002]...] etc

len(List1) = 152
len(List2) = 106
```

The numbers in each sublist essentially correspond to grid cell ID's, where the ID's for `List1` and `List2` come from the same grid with dimensions `(90x61)`. So there could be some clusters which contain similar groupings of ID's and hence why I want to do an ARI.

The problem I have is that the lists only represent a sub-sample of the entire grid and the length of these lists differs. `List1` and `List2` contain `1378` and `817` points respectively out of the total `5490` available.

Now because the lengths are different, unfortunately I cannot just run the following:

```
from sklearn.metrics.cluster import adjusted_rand_score
ARI = adjusted_rand_score(List1,List2)
```

As I get an error:

```
labels_true and labels_pred must have same size, got 152 and 106
```

So my **Question**:

What would be the most mathematically sound approach to make `List1` and `List2` the same size for the ARI calculation? Would making 46 more dummy clusters in `List2`, filled with arbitrary grid cells from the main grid which aren't yet in either list be silly?

Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sklearn implementations do not expect *sets*, but they expect an array of *labels*. This is more in line with the classification-oriented API of sklearn.

Furthermore, both need to include the same points. You probably should consider all remaining points unclustered, and assign them a unique label (as far as I know, sklearn does not support "noise" labels).

So you need to transform your data.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Indeed I had to transform both lists into two different Adjacency Matrices. From which I could create a single Contingency table and calculate the ARI from there.